# How to trigger a build only on changes in git master branch?

Tags: teamcity

What needs to be configured in TeamCity 7.1 that it triggers a build only when a commit happens to a master branch in git?

Currently, it triggers when changes to other (feature) branches are pushed to the remote repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh, seems like we had a service hook attached to TeamCity at GitHub, it was triggering those builds.

After turning off Github hook, build now it works as expected, builds only when pushed to master.

(Alternatively, hook can be configured to filter by branches)

Comment: Thanks for this. Turned out we had the same (in GitLab)